# How $f:[a,b]\rightarrow[c,d]$ should be read?

Tags: notation

I found it in a book but I don't know what the ":" means. What does this expression mean?

Comment: It should simply mean a function, with the preimage [a,b] and image [c,d]. An other example would be $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Here is a useful [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)), scroll down to the notation section

Comment: Sometimes I read it as "$f$ **takes** $[a,b]$ to $[c,d]$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that it is a function that maps the numbers in the interval $[a,b]$ to numbers in the interval $[c,d]$.  $[a,b]$ is the domain and $[c,d]$ is the codomain.

$f: X \rightarrow Y$ is fairly standard notation.

Example if $f(x) = x^2 - 7$ for $-1 \le x \le 5$ then $f:[-1,5] \rightarrow [-7,18]$ because $f$ maps the numbers in the interval $[-1,5]$ to the interval $[-7,18]$.

edited codomain.

Answer (score 1):

It means that $f$ is a function whose domain is the closed interval from $a$ to $b$ and whose codomain is the closed interval from $c$ to $d$.

Comment: @Vitor: The codomain can be larger than the image. The image is just the set of things you get when you put everything from your domain through the function. The codomain is just a set that the image is a part of.

Comment: a codomain is the set which might e mapped to.  The image is the set that *is* mapped to.  Image $\subset$ codomain.  Example if $f(x) = x^2 + 3x - 5$ we will say.. "that's a real function; it maps real number to real numbers-- the range/codomain is the real numbers".  With bit of work and effort we can notice that *actually* the image is ... well, I'm too lazy to work it out... and who cares?  We write $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ even though $f(x)$ is never actually less than negative whatever.

Comment: @Deusovi Thank you. I think I understood. if the image is {1,2.5,3} the codomain is [1,3]

Comment: @Vitor: Not necessarily. {1,2.5,3} can also be a codomain. You just need to give *some* codomain when you write down a function. It can be the same as the image, or it can be a superset of the image.

Answer (score 1):

We read $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ as "$f$ is a function from the closed interval $[a,b]$ to the closed interval $[c,d]$".

Alternatively, "$f$ maps the closed interval $[a,b]$ to the closed interval $[c,d]$".

In general, $f: A \rightarrow B$ means that $f$ is a function that maps elements from its domain $A$ to elements in its range $B$.